# getText() Method returns null when there is text

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, numberformatexception

Whenever I enter a number in my text box and get the text and convert it I get an exception:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
```

Here is the code for the class:

#### Number Generator:

```
package Main;

public class Number_Generator {

    public int makeRandom(){
        int Rnumber = 1;
        Rnumber = 1 + (int)(Math.random()*20);
        return Rnumber;
    }



}
```

### Oper_add:

```
package Main.Oper_classes;
import Main.Number_Generator;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import Main.Oper_check.*;

public class Oper_add {

    Number_Generator gen = new Number_Generator();
    public JTextField textbox = new JTextField(2);
    //make random numbers
            public Integer Rnumber1 = gen.makeRandom();
            public Integer Rnumber2 = gen.makeRandom();


    public void main(){
        //set textbox to null
        this.textbox.setText(null);

        //import classes
        Add_Check check = new Add_Check();
        //convert to String
        String Rnumber1S = Rnumber1.toString();
        String Rnumber2S = Rnumber2.toString();

        //make GUI
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Addition Test");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        FlowLayout fl = new FlowLayout();
        panel.setLayout(fl);

        JLabel num1 = new JLabel(Rnumber1S);
        JLabel sign = new JLabel("+");
        JLabel num2 = new JLabel(Rnumber2S);
        JLabel equals = new JLabel("=");
        JButton confirm = new JButton("Check");

        //add action listener
        confirm.addActionListener(check);

        //add componets to window
        panel.add(num1);
        panel.add(sign);
        panel.add(num2);
        panel.add(equals);
        panel.add(textbox);
        panel.add(confirm);

        //set frame settings
        frame.setContentPane(panel);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.pack();

    }

}
```

### add_check:

```
package Main.Oper_check;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import Main.Oper_classes.*;


public class Add_Check implements ActionListener {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        Oper_add add = new Oper_add();

        String textbox = add.textbox.getText().trim();
        Integer textboxC = Integer.parseInt(textbox);
        Integer total = add.Rnumber1 + add.Rnumber2;


    }

}
```

Comment: It seems `add.textbox` is empty.

Comment: @Eng.Fouad It isn't, I enter numbers suchas 2, and I still get this error

Comment: The textbox you're interacting with in your code is most certainly empty.  Odds are, the textbox in your GUI is not the same object as the one you're interacting with here.

Comment: @user2317720 Have you run the code through a debugger?  What about using a `System.out.println(textbox)` before the `Integer.parseInt` call?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Oper_add add = new Oper_add();
String textbox = add.textbox.getText().trim();
Integer textNumber = Integer.parseInt(textbox);
```

You are creating a new `Oper_add` which has a new, empty text box in it.  You're expecting that text box to have a value, but it won't.  It is in no way related to whatever text box you're interacting with.

Comment: Ok so do I just put the checker in the Oper_add?

Answer (score 1):

The text box currently has an empty string (or maybe just spaces -- `trim` removes spaces).  It doesn't have null.  The exception is because the empty string is not a valid number.  You should catch the exception and then use it in an JOptionPane:

```
try {
    Integer textNumber = Integer.parseInt(textbox);
     ...
} catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, ex.getMessage(), "Number Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
}
```

Comment: There is a number in it, it just doesn't recognize it

Comment: Aurand saw the problem: you are creating a new `Oper_add`.  The easiest solution is to declare the `Add_check` class as nested in the `Oper_add` class.  Then just access the `textbox` directly rather than creating a new new `Oper_add`.